# Shopify webhook for "new customer" notification

Tags: shopify

At Shopify needed to create webhook for notification (to my emaail) when new customer registrated.
What I need to paste in URL field (here http://pastexen.com/i/vzShV9IBfI.png)?
Can anybody help?

Comment: The URL that is to be pasted is the link to an app that'll able to parse the webhook information sent by Shopify and send you a mail based on it. You can try asking Shopify support for this specific need of yours. They'll be able to help you.

Comment: Also.. refer to this - https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/shopify-discussion/t/notification-on-user-signup-250966

Answer (score 0):

The URL field of the webhook specifies the endpoint url where the webhook response will be sent. As in your case you want to send an email on new user signup it would work like following:-

1. create a customer creation webhook in shopify.
2. create a new script or page(hosted outside shopify) that fetches the information from incoming file stream and uses some email server to send email.
3. at webhook creation pass
   the above script or page url in the URL field. Webhook will pass the
   data in the format as selected to this URL.

In this way you will be able to get email notification on customer creation.